# Agrandar tamaño de un card-body

Tags: html, css

Estoy en un proyecto de gestión de documentos de un hospital de mi país, lo que necesito lograr es que el recuadro que esta en morado se agrande un poco mas sin perder el orden de los datos de adentro. En la parte de abajo aparece un error pero en esa parte se despliega una lista con los datos especificados pero la lista queda con los datos muy apretados y eso es lo que se quiere arreglar, no se si se entiende lo que quiero lograr. El lenguaje que se esta ocupando es netamente HTML con CSS.

```html
<div class="col-9">
                <h1 class="text-center">Correspondencia</h1>
                <div class="card" black="" width:="20em" border:="1pm">
                    <div class="card-body " div.row="">

                        <div class="form-row">

                            <div class="form-group col-ms-auto col-md-2">
                                <h5 for="txt_oficio">Numero Oficio</h5>
                                <input type="number" class="form-control" id="txt_oficio" aria-describedby="Busqueda">
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group col-ms-auto">
                                <h5 for="txt_materia">Materia</h5>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="txt_materia" aria-describedby="Busqueda">
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group col-md-auto">
                                <h5 for="txt_vencimiento">Vencimiento</h5>
                                <input type="date" class="form-control" id="txt_vencimiento" aria-describedby="Busqueda">
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group col-md-2">
                                <h5 for="txt_estado">Estado</h5>
                                <select id="ddl_estado" style="width:100%">
                                    <option value="">Todos</option>
                                    <option value="Pendiente">Pendiente</option>
                                    <option value="Rechazado">Rechazado</option>
                                    <option value="Aprobado">Aprobado</option>
                                    <option value="Respondido">Respondido</option>
                                    <option value="Vencido">Vencido</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group col-md-2">
                                <h5 for="txt_estado">Tipo Documento</h5>
                                <select id="ddl_tipo_doc" style="width:100%">
                                    <option value="">Todos</option>
                                    <option value="IF">IF</option>
                                    <option value="LEN">LEN</option>
                                    <option value="GG-IF">GG-IF</option>
                                    <option value="Carta">Cartas Internas</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>

                        </div>

                        <button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="grillaGG()">Buscar</button>

                    </div>
                </div>
```

[image: se tiene que agrandar lo que esta marcado en morado]

Comment: Necesitamos conocer el `parent` del card, para poder saber qué estas usando.
Pero vamos, que no tiene nada, tienes dos `col` el izquierdo (el cuadro de opciones) y el derecho (el cuadro morado). Solo debes poner `div.row > (div.col-md-3 + div.col-md-9)` o lo que necesites. El máximo es 12 (3+9).

Comment: @S.Wasta El parent seria la pagina en general o me equivoco?

Comment: El `div` que engloba el card y todo lo que está en la parte derecha de la páguna, qué clases css tiene?

Comment: @S.Wasta como recien me pidieron hacerme cargo de la pagina, no soy consiente de las clases css que se ocuparon, como puedo ver eso y estoy ocupando el firefox developer para trabajar

Comment: @S.Wasta y el div que engloba al card seria <div class ="col-9"> esperame que cambio el fragmento del codigo

Comment: Eso era lo que quería. Vale, si cambias el `col-9` por un `col-10`, verás cómo se hace más grande. Ten en cuenta también que ese `col-9` tendrá un `div` hermano, que puede ser que tenga css `col-3` debes cambiarlo también a `col-2`. La web está usando bootstrap, échale un ojo. Para así poder editar la página a tu "gusto"

Comment: @S.Wasta master gracias por la ayuda, ahora voy a ver lo que me dijo y ya actualize el codigo dentro de la pregunta

Comment: @S.Wasta hice lo que me pusiste pero al hacer los cambios en los col, los card se mueven hacia abajo y como entro en el bootstrap desde firefox developer

Comment: bootstrap es el CSS, una librería/framework. https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/layout/grid/